# Visiting any locale gives the same locale output

Tags: localization

The site has 5 locales targeting `'en_gb', 'fr_fr', 'de_de', 'it_it', 'es_es'`. 
When I'm at `site.com` it gets current locale correctly `en_gb`. When I visit `site.com/fr/` locale, It loads blank page with current locale `en_gb`. The same scenario repeats for all locales, except the top level local `en_gb`.

I went through my settings multiple times, but I still wasn't able to find a problem.

My `general.php` settings:

```
return array(   

// Local environment
'site.craft.dev' => array(
    'devMode' => true,
    'environmentVariables' => array(
        'sitePath' => '/OS/Applications/MAMP/sites/site.craft.dev/public/',
        'siteUrl' => 'http://site.craft.dev/'
        ),
    'siteUrl' =>  array(
        'en_gb' => 'http://site.craft.dev/',
        'fr_fr' => 'http://site.craft.dev/fr/',
        'de_de' => 'http://site.craft.dev/de/',
        'it_it' => 'http://site.craft.dev/it/',
        'es_es' => 'http://site.craft.dev/es/',
        ),
    )
);
```

Public folders are structured  and set according to [documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/localization-guide#step-5-set-up-the-files), named after locale's handles like that: `fr_fr`, `de_de` etc.

and with `$craftPath` variable set to necessary `handle` like `fr_fr`, `de_de` etc.

When I visit site.craft.dev/fr/ and ask for current locale by `{{ craft.i18n.getCurrentLocale() }}`, it gives me default locale `en_gb`.

Comment: Have you set CRAFT_LOCALE in your index.php? `define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'fr_fr');` for the French one.

Comment: Yes I have for all the locales.

Comment: .htaccess for each locale?

Comment: @carlcs .htaccess for each locale

Comment: Same content != no content. What do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The craft path should be 1 level deeper like that '../../craft' instead of '../craft'. This is what was causing it, but I had to reconfigure the locales from `fr_fr` to `fr`. It didn't work in original way.